# Which online support model works better for a medical site?

Tags: website-design, customer-support, question-answer

I'm work on a medical site that needs to a Q&A sub-site.

I'm not sure which support system is better for users and authors of the site.

Ticket based support system seems better for private ticket that may contain private information from people to doctors...

Q&A support system can be useful for searching between similar medical question.

What is your recommend?

Comment: Any UX question like this cannot be answered without a full understanding of the intended audience. I've not talked to your end users and I hope you have. They should tell you what they want in terms of support and how they would prefer to have it.

Comment: Keep in mind there *may* be regulatory requirements pertaining to privacy when it comes to medical info

Answer (score 1):

Why not giving to your users the possibility to use both of them ? Many websites are doing this and I think that it's a good idea !
BTW you could also suggest some similar questions of the Q&A section to a user sending a ticket so he might find himself the answer to his question.